# React Native Error: Actions must be plain objects, Use Custom Middleware for Aync Actions

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I am applying redux-thunk for the first time as part of the login process. I get the error below (red screen):

[image]

Here is my code repo: 
https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4

Code snippets below:

LoginForm.js:

my code repo is here: https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4

Code Snippets here:

Actions/index.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { EMAIL_CHANGED,
         PASSWORD_CHANGED,
         LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS
 } from './types';
//whenever the const variable below (action creator) is called
//it will be called with some amount of text and it returns an action, the text
//which is entered as an argument becomes the payload below
export const emailChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};
export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  //since we are using redux thunk/ async, the action creator now returns a function
  //instead of an object. Redux Thunk will see that this is a function and run it
  //the "then" will dispatch once the function is finisehd running
  return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(user => {
      dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: user });
  });
};
};
```

loginform.js:

```
//we need this component to use react components library
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//this connect helper that will connect the action to the login form
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
//this is an action creator that we need to import in to connect with the reducers
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';
//these are our pre-styled components
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';

//login form is declared as an instance of the class "component"
class Loginform extends Component {
// this is the event handler as a method whose argument is text
  onEmailChange(text) {
//we have access to this prop from the action creator that is connected via the connect helper
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
  }
  onPasswordChange(text) {
    this.props.passwordChanged(text);
  }

  onButtonPress() {
const { email, password } = this.props;
this.props.loginUser({ email, password });  
  }
  render() {
    return (

    <Card>
      <CardSection>
        <Input
          label="Email"
          placeholder="email@gmail.com"
          onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
//this comes from mapStateToProps and WE tell the component what its value is
//via the action creator and the reducer
          value={this.props.email}
        />
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection>
        <Input
          secureTextEntry
          label="Password"
          placeholder="password"
          onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.props.password}
        />
      </CardSection>

      <CardSection>
        <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
          Login
        </Button>
      </CardSection>
    </Card>
  );
  }
}
//this function is from the react-redux library and helps to map some piece of state
//onto the component
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
//the global state object contains another object called auth, which containts the email
//property
    email: state.auth.email,
    password: state.auth.password
  };
};

//we are connecting/binding our action creator via the connect helper
//mapStateToProps is the first argument in the connect function
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser
})(Loginform);
```

REDUCER:

```
//this is importing the email changed variable instead of the string in the action
import { EMAIL_CHANGED,
         PASSWORD_CHANGED
 } from '../actions/types';

//we need to do this otherwise the initial value will be undefined and the
//action will not work
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  email: '',
  password: ''
};

//this is the reducer below, its got 2 arguments, the state and action
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);
//this switch statement switches over the action type, and depending on type
//the action decides what to do with it
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:
    console.log('action!');
//make a new object, take all the properties of my current object and include in
//that new object and take the email action.payload and include/overwrite that
//in the new object created
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };
    case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, password: action.payload };
  //if none of the cases come out to be true above, it will default to the
  //beginning state with no changes
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
//reduxthnunk is helping us with aync operations, its a middlware
//to help with this middleware we need a ahelper from Redux library
//
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCCEY-CD1iSpSowupPZJcSuHEQ_yLvVzhg',
    authDomain: 'manager-2714d.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://manager-2714d.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'manager-2714d',
    storageBucket: 'manager-2714d.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '191493388327'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
          <Provider store={store}>
          <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can see in your snippets where you have applied `redux-thunk` to handle the async call, but [it's not there in github](https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4/blob/master/src/App.js#L28).  Just in case, are you sure `App.js` has actually been saved with `applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)` in it?

Comment: Hi- I exported that entire folder to Guthub so Shld Be there...I’ll check...

Comment: i looked at the repo and redux-thunk is there in the app.js file @MichaelPeyper. It has been saved correctly. app.js file is in the src folder pls check if you would like. Thanks!

Comment: I can see it being imported, but not applied. Line 28: https://github.com/samrao2/manager-4/blob/master/src/App.js#L28

Comment: you are right, somehow the file App.js had not saved, even though i had pressed command +s several times in atom editor, i had not done so for that file. Once i went in  and saved that particular file, the issue was resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the file app.js was not properly saved as evidenced by the following code in the github repo that does not contain the thunk elements that would make this code work:

```
  render() {
    return (
          <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
          <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The code in that same file that would make this work is:

```
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    return (
          <Provider store={store}>
          <LoginForm />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Saving the file properly resolved the issue.